# How can I send messages in background of an android app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create an app which can send firebase push messages to the phone. this works now. But when I close the app I also want to get the same push messages like in the app.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution. I found IntentService but I am not sure how to use it with the push notifications.

**Update:**
I used the firebase tutorial. My service class:

```
package com.example.kai.msgtest;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Uri sound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mail_white_18dp)
                .setContentTitle("Sie haben Post")
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Some of your code would be useful for people to evaluate the situation.

Comment: This could be an easy fix, but without seeing your code (the part that handles the sent message) and an example of the message you are sending, we really can't help.

Comment: You must learn [functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhtruseOP2gIVEyUrCh3k1w-aEAAYASAAEgJe8PD_BwE).
once your concept is clear, then you could send notifications even when the apps are closed/background.

Comment: Your Service class looks correct. Have you added it to the Manifest?

Comment: yes, I did. the notification when the app is open works good. when i close the app, the notification appears but without any sound and with a default/fallback icon in the system tray. I read some about this behavior but i didnt understand how to handle this so that I can have the same notification like in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the fcm api. I configured some things like the displayed icon in the fcm message like this:

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<serverkey>" \
--Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d "{\"to\":\"<device-token>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"test\", \"icon\":\"ic_mail_white_18dp\"},\"priority\":10}"
```

After that, the icon appears like when the app is in foreground